# Jquery Autocomplete unable to read Array of Objects

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to use a JSON output from the server as the source for my autocomplete function. I read the Autocomplete documentation and it does say that Array of Objects is accepted as a source type. Can someone please let me know where am I going wrong with this?

```
            jq( document ).ready(function() {
            jq("body").css({overflow:'hidden'});

            jq.getJSON("<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . "setsession/index/getarea"; ?>",
             function(data) {

                jq( "#autocomplete-1" ).autocomplete({
                source: data,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.item.area_id);
                    jq("#splash_area").val(ui.item.area_id);
                    return false;
                }
                });
            }
            );              
            });
```

This is what I am getting back from the server (JSON encoded):

```
[{"area_id":"1","area_name":"DLF Phase 1"},{"area_id":"2","area_name":"DLF Phase 2"}]
```

Comment: you mean your autocomplete dropdown doesn't show anything ?

Comment: thats right. The autocomplete is not showing the dropdown. When I supply a single dimesional array then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation it states an `An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Your objects are not defined this way. So for your example something like

[{value:"1",label:"DLF Phase 1"},{value:"2",label:"DLF Phase 2"}]

Comment: Worked. I never suspected them to take away the independence of naming the data type!